# How do I solve $5^x = x^2$?

Tags: calculus

How do I solve the equation in the title?
This was in a Calculus text book that did not show the answer to this.

Comment: It didn't show the answer probably because it expected you to find it.

Comment: What does this have to do with calculus?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Edit your post to contain your thoughts and work on the problem, and then others will help guide you.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \ge 0$ then $5^x > x^2$, and if $x \le -1$ then $5^x < x^2$, as can be proved by considering derivatives.

Now $5^{-1} = \frac{1}{5} < 1 = (-1)^2$, and $5^0 = 1 > 0 = 0^2$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is a solution to the equation $5^x=x^2$ with $x \in ({-1}, 0)$. Moreover, this solution is unique since on this interval $x \mapsto 5^x$ is increasing and $x \mapsto x^2$ is decreasing.

So with the knowledge that a solution $x$ to the equation $5^x=x^2$ exists, you need to find $x$. Unfortunately no closed form for its value exists, but you can use numerical methods to find what the value of $x$ is to within any fixed margin of error.

Comment: Actually, a closed form does exist.

Comment: @Dr.MV: That depends on what you mean by *closed form*; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Expressing a quantity in terms of the Lambert $W$-function usually doesn't constitute giving it a closed-form expression, since it isn't an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Comment: And we see voluminous references to closed form solutions in terms of other "special functions."  But I would suggest that if we have a well-known function with a known power series, functional relationships, known values at discrete points, asymptotic expansions, then we have a function that is no different in kind from the so-called elementary functions. What are the trigonometric functions, exponential, logarithm, etc.?  How are they defined?  All in terms of limiting processes.  So, I ask "What is the real difference aside from frequency of use?

Comment: @Dr.MV: If *closed form* means something different to you from what it does to me, then that's okay. The notion of an elementary function is well established, and it's those functions that I refer to when I say *closed form*, and I know I'm not alone in this convention. This (tiny) issue is a matter of semantics, and not correctness, which is why I was puzzled by your first comment, which frankly seemed more aggressive than was necessary.

Comment: Sincerely, I certainly did not intend to offend or be "aggressive."   Rather, I was only stating an observation that I have made.  If I can get an answer in terms of a Bessel function, a Gamma function, etc., or combinations thereof, then that is closed form, I believe.  And I really would like to hear your answer to my last question which was "What is the real difference aside from frequency of use (common use perhaps) or the so-called elementary functions and the so-called special functions?"  All require limiting processes to define.

Comment: One additional thing ... and I am not trying to beat this issue, but the citation that you referenced [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression) discusses considering functions such as Gamma as an elementary function.  So, perhaps we will agree to disagree on this issue.  But there is absolutely no ill will. Your answer was more likely better "fit-for-purpose" here.  So, well done!!

Answer (score 2):

Is this problem in a section regarding Newton's Method of successive approximations?

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Let $f(x) = x^2 -5^x$. We want $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Since  $f(0) = -1$ and $f(-1)=0.8$, there appears to be a zero in the interval $x \in (-1,0)$.

---

We can choose $x_1 = -1$ and apply Newton's method until reaching the desired accuracy. To use Newton's Method, we need $f'(x) = 2x - 5^x \ln5$.

$x_{2} = x_1 - \frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)} = -1 - \frac{4/5}{-2 - 5^{-1} \ln5} \approx -0.65545$

$x_{3} = x_2 - \frac{f(x_2)}{f'(x_2)} \approx -0.61196$

$x_{4} = x_3 - \frac{f(x_3)}{f'(x_3)} \approx -0.61140$

$x_{5} = x_4 - \frac{f(x_4)}{f'(x_4)} \approx -0.61140$

$\boxed{x \approx -0.61140}$

Let's check...

$f(-0.61140) \approx 9.7 \times 10^{-7}$

If that's small enough for your liking, you've got your approximation. If not, use more decimal places in the steps above.

Comment: Actually, a closed form exists.

Comment: @Dr.MV  I have a hunch that since this problem was found in a calculus textbook, then the poster might want it to be approached by introductory calculus techniques.

Comment: Your suspicion is likely spot on.  And your answer here is solid.  Well done.  I am only trying to raise awareness, that is all.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we can find a closed form solution in terms of the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  We simply note that the $W$ function is defined as the solution to

$$z=W(z)e^{W(z)} \tag 1$$

Then for $x<0$, starting with $5^x=x^2$ we take the logarithm of both sides and find

$$x\log 5=2 \log| x| \tag 2$$

Next, we divide both sides of $(2)$ by $2$ and use $\frac12 \log 5=\log 5^{1/2}$ to obtain

$$x\log 5^{1/2}=\log |x|\tag 3$$

whereupon exponentiation of both sides of $(3)$ reveals

$$e^{-|x|\log 5^{1/2}}=|x| \tag 4$$

Finally, we bring the exponential and linear terms to one side and multiply both sides of the result by $\log 5^{1/2}$ to obtain

$$(|x|\log 5^{1/2})e^{|x|\log 5^{1/2}}=\log 5^{1/2} \tag 5$$

whereupon comparison to $(1)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=-2\frac{W\left(\frac12\log 5\right)}{\log 5}\approx. -0.611399468715555024901
}$$

where we used the approximation for $W\left(\frac12\log 5\right)\approx. 0.49200474104107505485$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the solution posted by Clive. You can get an idea by plotting the curves.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$f(x) = 5^x-x^2\;,$$ Then $$f'(x) = 5^x\cdot \ln(5)-2x$$

and $$f''(x) = 5^x\cdot [\ln(5)]^2-2$$ and $$f'''(x)=5^x\cdot \cdot [\ln(5)]^3>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

So Using $\bf{IMVT}$ Theorem If $f'''(x)=0$ has no roots, Then $f''(x) =0 $ has at most $1$ roots

and $f'(x) =0$ has at most $2$ roots and $f(x)=0$ has at most $3$ roots.

Now for $f(x) = 5^x-x^2\;,$ at $x=-1\;,$ we get $\displaystyle f(-1) = -\frac{1}{5}-1=-\frac{6}{5}<0$ and $f(0)=1>0$

So one root of $f(x) =0$ lie between $(-1,0)$

Now when $x<-1\;,$ we get $f(x)<0$ and for $x>0\;,$ we get $f(x) = 5^x-x^2>0$

So there is exactly one root of $f(x) =0$ which lie between $(-1,0)$

Comment: Actually, a closed form exists.