# X raised to power-X raised to power-3 equals to 3.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

The question is what are the possible values of $x$ when we have

$$x^{x^3} = 3$$

(that is $x^3$ in the exponent itself and not $x*3$).

I solved one answer by guessing that $x = \sqrt[3]3$. My work is below however I was only able to solve it assuming $x = \sqrt[3]3$, can anyone solve it without the assumption. I suspect that logarithms are involved which I have to review. Also there are supposed to be more solutions to this than just the one mentioned. Thanks in advance and enjoy. It's a fun problem[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU36P.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one wishes to use logarithms to facilitate then we proceed accordingly. We have that

$$x^{x^3}=3\implies x^3\log x=\log 3\implies x^3\log x^3=\log 3^3 \implies (x^3)^{x^3}=3^3$$

Of course this result could be obtained instantly by simply cubing both sides of the original equation.

Therefore a solution is evidently $x^3=3$ or $x=3^{1/3}$.

Given that $x^x$ is monontoically increasing for $x>1/e$, then $x=3^{1/3}$ is the only real-valued solution.

Comment: You could have just cubed the original equation.

Comment: @CarlHeckman I thought that the OP had asked about the use of the log function.  Perhaps I misunderstood. In either case, the analysis is correct.

Comment: Using logs muddles the basic idea: Manipulate the equation to get one of the form $y^y=z^z$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Yes and thank you.  +1 I edited to add some language around that. But the OP definitely requested some guidance on the use of logarithms, and so I kept that analysis herein for support.

Comment: Since the unique positive solution to $x^x=a$ is $\frac{\ln a}{W(\ln a)}$, where $W$ is the Lambert-W function, you can thus solve equations like $x^{x^3}=4$: Cube both sides, then $x^3=\frac{\ln 64}{W(\ln 64)}$, $x=\root 3 \of {\frac{\ln 64}{W(\ln 64)}}$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman I am well aware of the $W$ function, but that would not be instructive here, in my humble opinion. See for example [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384870/how-do-i-solve-5x-x2/1384903#1384903).

Comment: How do you show that $y=x^x$ is increasing for $x>0$?

Comment: @user84413 Thanks. $x>1/e$ ....  a +1 for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
x^{(x^3)}&=3\\
x^{(x^3)}&=\sqrt[3]{3}^{(\sqrt[3]{3}^3)}
\end{align*}$$
So that base are same, hence 
$$x = \sqrt[3]{3}$$